# HTML - Reducing html code redundancy

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if there is a way to shorten my HTML code. I'm currently using bootstrap for laying out this webpages.

The menu on my page is repeated throughout the pages and if it gets updated, you update page by page.

Is there perhaps any way to shorten the whole HTML code...

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"
    <div class="container">
        ...
    </div>
<div>
```

... by using javascript or any in any kind of way.

Comment: lol wth? why would you do that , wont it reduce funtionality

Comment: I'll be honest with you, this is a worthless question you asked, because you supplied no code to work from. This isn't a hypothetical discussion site. This is a place to ask legitimate questions. But to guide you, you're looking to do an include of shared elements, by way of PHP or the like.

Comment: Be specific with your questions.

Comment: *"you update page by page."* - Only if you have static HTML pages. Normally there is some server side code as well, which will generate a menu and other repeating elements from a template.

Comment: there are many ways reduce redundancy, you can check angularjs nginclude

Comment: Sorry for not being able to post the code earlier. I didn't know the format used to block the code while using my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - you can do it through javascript. Lets assume you create 1 js file that you include in all your pages:

```
<script language="javascript" src="/js/mymenu.js"></script>
```

If you use another javascript, or other css files for your menu, make sure to include the mymenu.js file BEFORE the others in your HEAD tag.

Then in your mymenu.js file just have some code like this:

```
var outerDiv = document.createElement("div");
outerDiv.setAttribute("class","navbar navbar-fixed-top");
outerDiv.setAttribute("role","navigation");
var innerDiv = document.createElement("div");
innerDiv.setAttribute("class","container");
outerDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
document.body.appendChild(outerDiv);
...
```

Make sure your css for the main menu uses position: absolute; or instead of doing body.appendChild, append it to the containing element.

Comment: It's a long process making this but it worked! Thanks!